# How to add a "display layout"/"view_method" to a folder?

Tags: plone

When you visit a folder in plone, its default view is determined by what you've previously selected in the "Display" menu, for example, "Summary view", "standard view", etc. Those options are defined in Products/CMFPlone/profiles/default/types/Folder.xml, with the view_methods tag:

```
<property name="view_methods">
  <element value="folder_summary_view"/>
  <element value="folder_full_view"/>
  <element value="folder_tabular_view"/>
  <element value="atct_album_view"/>
  <element value="folder_listing"/>
</property>
```

And those views are defined at Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_content.

How can I add my own element to view_method in folders, using another package? How can I override Folder.xml? And where do I put the new template?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to create profiles/default/types/Folder.xml containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="Folder">
 <property name="view_methods" purge="False">
  <element value="my_view"/>
 </property>
</object>
```

and then register it into profiles/default/types.xml:

```
[...]
<object name="Folder"
        meta_type="Factory-based Type Information with dynamic views" />
[...]
```